# Google analytics profile not retrieved to my site

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using [google analytics counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter). I have Google analytics account and created OAuth2 credentials. My site got authenticated to Google analytics API after adding credentials to my site. But no Google analytics profile retrieved on my site, and below warning thrown.

Please help in this regard.

thanks

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in google_analytics_counter_auth_admin() (line 90 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in google_analytics_counter_auth_admin() (line 91 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in google_analytics_counter_auth_admin() (line 117 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in google_analytics_counter_auth_admin() (line 126 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
Notice: Undefined variable: current_profile in google_analytics_counter_auth_admin() (line 146 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme_google_analytics_counter_profile_label() (line 273 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme_google_analytics_counter_profile_label() (line 273 of /home/bytescom/public_html/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_auth.inc).
```